# Problems Serializing a Form and Converting It to a Complex Class in Asp.net Core MVC to Post a Whole Model Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-ajax

I am serializing my ASP.NET form so that it will be converted according to my PessoaViewModel complex class. Apparently, serialization occurs correctly, but when I post using ajax, paratically 98% of fields are loaded with null value. Below I posted a piece of the serialized class:

ExibirTelaPesquisaCpfCnpjAntesCadastrarPessoa=False&PessoaViewModel.Id=2&PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza=Juridica&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoaId=2&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto=JALBER%20ROMANO&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.Apelido=BIM&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.DataNascimento=2019-11-18&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.Sexo=Masculino&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.EstadoCivil=Solteiro&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoaFisicaOrigem=Brasileiro&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.Id=3&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.PessoaId=2&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.EnderecoTipoDescricao=COBRAN%C3%87A&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.RotuloEnderecoTipo=Endere%C3%A7o%20de%20cobran%C3%A7a%20%C3%A9%20utilizado%20para%20definir%20o%20local%20de%20cobran%C3%A7a%20de%20mercadorias%20adquiridas%20pelos%20clientes.&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.EnderecoTipoId=3&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.PaisId=1&PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel%5B0%5D.CodigoPostal=29780-000&......

JS:

```
var pessoaViewModel = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/change-pessoa-natureza",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pessoaViewModel: pessoaViewModel}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {
        stopLoadModalInside();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }
});
```

Asp.Net Core MVC (
(Controller, PessoaViewModel Class, and subclasses)):

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza")]
    public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    public string PessoaNaturezaDescricao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Naturezas")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }

    public PessoaFisicaViewModel PessoaFisicaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaJuridicaViewModel PessoaJuridicaViewModel { get; set; }

    public List<PessoaGenericoViewModel> PessoasGenericosViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<PessoaContatoViewModel> PessoasContatosViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<PessoaDocumentoViewModel> PessoasDocumentosViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<PessoaEnderecoViewModel> PessoasEnderecosViewModel { get; set; }

    //Configuracoes
    //public bool AtivarBloqueioRedundanciaCpfCnpj { get; set; }
    public bool ExibirTelaPesquisaCpfCnpjAntesCadastrarPessoa { get; set; }

    //DropDownList Novo Contato
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FormasContato { get; set; }

    //DropDownList Novo Endereco
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnderecosTipos { get; set; }

    //DropDownList
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentosTipos { get; set; }

    // public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentosOrgaosEmissores { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Paises { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel()
    {
        PessoasNaturezas = ExtensaoDeEnumerador.EnumParaSelectListGenerico<PessoaNatureza>("U", PessoaNatureza.ToString()).OrderBy(x => x.Text);
        PessoaFisicaViewModel = null;
        PessoaJuridicaViewModel = null;
    }
}


 public class PessoaDocumentoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pessoa")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Pessoa")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo de Documento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha um Tipo de Documento")]
    public int DocumentoTipoId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentoTipoDescricao { get; set; }
    public string RotuloDocumentoTipo { get; set; }
    public string DocumentoTipoSigla { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Documento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Número do Documento é obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Documento { get; set; }

    public PessoaDocumentoDataEmissaoViewModel PessoaDocumentoDataEmissaoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoDataPrimeiraEmissaoViewModel PessoaDocumentoDataPrimeiraEmissaoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoDataVencimentoViewModel PessoaDocumentoDataVencimentoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoDataExpedicaoViewModel PessoaDocumentoDataExpedicaoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoOrgaoEmissorViewModel PessoaDocumentoOrgaoEmissorViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoZonaViewModel PessoaDocumentoZonaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoSecaoViewModel PessoaDocumentoSecaoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoCategoriaViewModel PessoaDocumentoCategoriaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoSerieViewModel PessoaDocumentoSerieViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoPaisViewModel PessoaDocumentoPaisViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaDocumentoUFViewModel PessoaDocumentoUFViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentosTipos { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentosOrgaosEmissores { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Paises { get; set; }

}


[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/change-pessoa-natureza")]
public PartialViewResult ChangePessoaNatureza([FromBody] PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{

    return null;
}
```

[image]

As far as I studied, serialization uses only fields that are neither null nor empty. Why isn't it working? Are there invalid characters in field names since many of them are within Lists?
Does anyone know how to help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you serializing your form to a url-encoded string and then that string to Json? Maybe you could just post the form to your controller and decorate the viewmodel  parameter od the controller action method with a FromForm attribute  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: The reason I have to post is because I need to scroll some field information as the user selects some option in select. It would not be a submit, but a post to exchange some information.

Comment: You mean something like this : user fills out part of the form then you post it then user sees more options and goes on with filling the rest of the form?

Comment: More or less that. For example, the user selects an option from a select and some fields will not be needed and others will need to be displayed. Then a post should be made to send ViewModel to the server and update. Then it will be returned to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use .serialize(), it generates the data in a 'query string' format which needs to be sent using the default contentType which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, not as JSON.

Either remove the `contentType` option or specify contentType: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`:

```
@model PessoaViewModel
<form>
    <input asp-for="PessoaNaturezaDescricao" />
    <input asp-for="ExibirTelaPesquisaCpfCnpjAntesCadastrarPessoa" />
    ...
    <input asp-for="PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].PessoaId" />
    <input asp-for="PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" />
    <input type="button" onclick="test()"/>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function test()
    {
        var pessoaViewModel = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/change-pessoa-natureza",
            type: "POST",
            data: pessoaViewModel,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function () {
                stopLoadModalInside();
                alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
            }
        });
            }

</script>
}
```

Also,you need to change `FromBody` to `FromForm` like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/change-pessoa-natureza")]
public PartialViewResult ChangePessoaNatureza([FromForm] PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{

    return null;
}
```